# tar: How to create a tar file with arbitrary leading directories w/o 'cd'ing to parent dir

Tags: compression, tar

Say I have a directory of files at

```
/home/user1/dir1
```

and I want to create a tar with only "dir1" as the leading directory:

```
/dir1/file1
/dir1/file2
```

I know I can first cd to the directory

```
cd /home/user1/
tar czvf dir1.tar.gz dir1
```

But when writing scripts, jumping from directory to directory isn't always favorable. I am wondering is there a way to do it with absolute paths without changing current directories?

I know I can always create a tar file with absolute paths INSIDE and use

```
--strip-components
```

when extracting but sometimes extra path names are extra private information that you don't want to distribute with your tar files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

tar -C changes directory

```
tar -C /home/user1/ -cvzf dir1.tar.gz dir1
```

btw, handy one for keeping track of changing directories... use pushd and popd.

```
pushd .
cd /home/user1
tar cvfz dir1.tar.gz
popd
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that "-C" option has to be used before other options... I tried "tar -cvzf dir1.tar.gz dir1 -C /home/user1/" before but it didn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work: tar: dir: Cannot stat: No such file or directory (assuming dir1 is under /home/user1/)

Comment: @tribbloid See https://superuser.com/a/266429/100853 (I just faced the same problem)

Answer (score 32):

With gnu tar, you can create an archive with a different base directory than the actual with:

```
tar -c --transform 's,^\.,mybasedir,' .
```

Just adapt the sed expression to your needs.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I also found out that

```
tar -czvf file1.tar.gz /home/user1/dir1/../dir1
```

also worked the way I wanted.

Comment: Although wildcards like "*" then do not work

Answer (score 2):

```
tar -C /home/user1/dir -c .
```

Answer (score 0):

I used bellow command to create tar for whole files in some directory,

```
tar -C ${filePath} -cvzf test.tar.gz $(ls ${filePath})
```